# Count with two aggregate conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like this:

```
User_id, transaction_id, transaction_cost,  transaction_type 
1000, 2000, 123, a
1000, 2001, 234, a
1000, 2002, 345, b
1001, 2003, 456, b
1001, 2004, 567, b
```

And want to get these user_ids, which fulfill two conditions:

```
1 - their summed transactions cost > 500
2 - the transactions they made have at least two types
```

Is there a nice way to check two aggregate conditions in one legible select and get a list of distinct user_ids as a result?
Thank you!

Comment: Show the results you want to get.

Comment: I want user_ids that pass two conditions I wrote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want user ids that pass the conditions:

```
select user_id
from t
group by user_id
having sum(transaction_cost) > 500 and
       count(distinct transaction_type) >= 2;
```

Comment: Very nice! I didn't know having is so powerful - thanks!